# How to control pywwt in jupyterLab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, astronomy

I'm using **pywwt** from World Wide Telescope in JupyterLab to make my program.

The goal is to scan [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcUwc.jpg) and find which part of the star sky is it. It will also show an image that looks the same but has already been marked with all the star signs in the picture.

To achieve the goal, I need to control the pywwts' camera and get screenshots from it programmatically.
But I don't know which function I should choose.

I tried to read the docs from their page. But I am still confused about how to control it. And I haven't found any way to take a screenshot. Or, does there any way that I can get the image that it's displaying?

[Here](https://pywwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pywwt.core.BaseWWTWidget.html#pywwt.core.BaseWWTWidget) is the document talking about the functions pywwt contains.